# How can I add a list of values to a dictionary where the first element in the list belongs to the first key and so on...?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary which has predefined keys:

```
{1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None}
```

and a list with numeric values:

```
[0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 100]
```

I want to add these values from the list to the dictionary so that it will look like this:

```
{1: 0, 2: 10, 3: 20, 4: 30, 5: 40, 6: 50, 7: 60, 8: 100}
```

How can I add every item from the list to the next key of my dictionary?

Comment: `{key:val for key,val in zip(m_dict.keys(), m_list)}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You directly use `zip` on the dict and the list of values, tha make pairs, then ues `dict` to make mappings from pairs

```
d = {1: None, 2: None, 3: None, 4: None, 5: None, 6: None, 7: None, 8: None}
v = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 100]

res = dict(zip(d, v))

print(res) # {1: 0, 2: 10, 3: 20, 4: 30, 5: 40, 6: 50, 7: 60, 8: 100}
```

You could find strange to passe the whole dict `d` to `zip` but iterating over th dict is same as iterating over its key in fact, the following can have more sense but it does the same

```
dict(zip(d.keys(), v))
```

Comment: is there a possibility that dictionary keys are not picked up sequentially?

Answer (score 0):

Below is more dynamic solution where you dont have prepare half populated dict

```
a_list = [0, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 100] 
a_dict = {idx+1:val for idx,val in enumerate(a_list)}
print(a_dict)
```

output

```
{1: 0, 2: 10, 3: 20, 4: 30, 5: 40, 6: 50, 7: 60, 8: 100}
```